# please answer that question for me

Tags: phrase-request, grammaticality-in-context

In my book there is the text:

> A ladybug crawled up a blade of grass in front of me. I wondered if it was really a female. **What would you call a male ladybug?** Funny what you focus on when your life is about to end.

I can't understand question in bold. Can you give me answer or answers to that question so that I will be able to understand it, no matter it will be funny or not funny answers.

Answer (score 1):

Ladybug or ladybird is the common name for [Coccinellidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccinellidae), a family of beetles.  They are named after "Our Lady" (Mary from Christianity), but like any species of beetle there are both male and female beetles.  However "lady" in itself is a term for woman or female, so the idea of a 'male ladybug' creates a mild linguistic 'paradox'.

Comment: [there are both male and female, not have].